# Modify group of values between a range

Tags: python, list, performance, time-complexity

I have a list of index ranges structured as `[(2, 4), (6, 7)]`.
I also have an array with 10 elements with all False values:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

What I wanna do is modify the values between these ranges and make them True. So the final list would be:

```
[False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False]
```

NB: the indexes of the list doesn't start from zero.

I was thinking of a solution based on two for's, but it has a N^2 complexity:

```
for i in range(len(list_ranges)):
    for j in range(len(my_list)):
        if (j >= list_ranges[i][0] or j <= list_ranges[i][1]):
            my_list[j] = True
```

How can I improve the complexity of the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update only the corresponding slice of list(modifies list in-place, which you're already doing with `my_list`). List set-slice is an [O(K) operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) if the count of items being set are equal.

```
>>> list_ranges = [(2, 4), (6, 7)]
>>> my_list = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> list_ranges = [(2, 4), (6, 7)]
>>> for start, end in list_ranges:
...     my_list[start-1:end] = [True] * (end - start + 1)
...
>>> my_list
[False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Note that this will start intermediate lists in memory and then assign those to the corresponding indices in the original list.

---

Secondly, if the ranges list is comparatively small, then we could check if the index lies within any of the ranges given.

```
>>> def solve(indices, my_list):
...     return [any(start <= index <= end for start, end in indices) for index, item in enumerate(my_list, start=1)]
...
>>> my_list = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> solve(ranges, my_list)
[False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False]
```